# Why DataBinding can't find a property which exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have declared a class but when I try to access it's members I get the following error :
 DataBinding: 'reapTest.Toop' does not contain a property with the name 'Rang'.

WebForm1.aspx.cs :

```
namespace reapTest {

    public class Toop {
        public string Rang;
        public int Gheymat;
    }

    public static class MyData {

        public static Toop[] TP = new Toop[] { new Toop() { Rang = "Ghermez", Gheymat = 100 }, new Toop() { Rang = "Yellow", Gheymat = 44 } };
        public static Toop[] RT() {
            return TP;
        }

    }

    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }
    }
}
```

WebForm1.aspx :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="reapTest.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("Rang")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        <asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="ObjectDataSource1" SelectMethod="RT" TypeName="reapTest.MyData"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe it is because it is looking for a *literal* property named Rang. You have a field named Rang, but that's not the same as a property. Just a thought.

Comment: @David, that thought would make a good answer :)

Comment: @DavidW The amazing is that I could get it working when I ran website for first time. Right after next compile the error came..

Comment: After thinking about it, I think you're right, @FrédéricHamidi :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it is because it is looking for a literal *property* named Rang. You have a *field* named Rang, but that's not the same as a property, to-wit:

EDIT: Code sample

```
public class Toop {

     // These values are *fields* within the class, but *not* "properties." 
     private string m_Rang; // changing these field decls to include m_ prefix for clarity
     private int m_Gheymat; // also changing them to private, which is a better practice

     // This is a public *property* procedure
     public string Rang     
     {
         get
         {
             return m_Rang;
         }
         set
         {
             m_Rang = value;
         }
     }
}
```

Fields and Properties are related in that Properties provide a public "wrapper" mechanism to the "private" field data of each instance of the class. But it is critical to note that they are separate concepts, and not interchangeable. Merely having a field declaration (also called a member in some object parlance) does not expose it as a property. Note what @FrédéricHamidi said - the docs state the `"value of the expression parameter must evaluate to a public **property**"`(emphasis mine).

As noted in this excerpt *directly from Microsoft*, EVAL, one way or the other, has to have a *property*.

[image]

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: This can't be the answer because again I have modified `<%#Eval("Rang")%>` to <%# "Hi" %> and I get two Hi. So that means my data is determined...

Comment: @Mahdi, `Eval("Rang")` will return the empty string (or `null`, not sure) because `Rang` is not a public property but a public field. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx) explicitly mentions `the value of the expression parameter must evaluate to a public property`. Binding string literals works because `Eval()` is not involved.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I have double checked my Container.DataItem and it has both public fields.

Comment: @Mahdi But what we're saying is that you must expose a public *PROPERTY*, not just the field. Please see my modified answer for details.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks now I got what you mean. accepted and approved